# How to check if arguments have been correctly passed to Rscript on Windows

Tags: r, command-line, parameters, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write an R script that takes in 3 arguments when run with Rscript: input file name, whether it has a header or not (values are 'header' or 'no_header', and a positive integer (the number of replacements; its for a bootstrap application). So, when I run it this way:

```
Rscript bootstrapWithReplacement.R survival.csv header 50
```

it should, before running, check if:
1) The script indeed took in 3 parameters;
2) whether the first parameter is a file;
3) whether the second parameter has a 'header' or 'no_header' value, and
4) if the number passed is a positive integer.

Here is my code so far:

```
pcArgs      <- commandArgs()
snOffset    <- grep('--args', pcArgs)
inputFile <- pcArgs[snOffset+1]
headerSpec <- pcArgs[snOffset+2]    ## header/no_header
numberOfResamples <- pcArgs[snOffset+3] ## positive integer

check.integer <- function(N){
    !length(grep("[^[:digit:]]", as.character(N)))
}

if (!file_test("-f",inputFile)) {stop("inputFile not defined. Proper use: Rscript bootstrapWithReplacementFile.R survival.csv header 50.")}
if (!exists("headerSpec")) {stop("headerSpec not defined. Proper use: Rscript bootstrapWithReplacementFile.R survival.csv header 50.")} 
if (!exists("numberOfResamples")) {stop("numberOfResamples not defined. Proper use: Rscript bootstrapWithReplacementFile.R survival.csv header 50.")} 

if ((headerSpec != 'header') == TRUE & (headerSpec != 'no_header') == TRUE) {stop("headerSpec not properly defined. Correct values: 'header' OR 'no_header'.")}
if (check.integer(numberOfResamples) != TRUE | (numberOfResamples>0) != TRUE) {stop("numberOfResamples not properly defined. Must be an integer larger than 0.")}


if (headerSpec == 'header') {
    inputData<-read.csv(inputFile)
    for (i in 1:numberOfResamples) {write.csv(inputData[sample(nrow(inputData),replace=TRUE),], paste("./bootstrap_",i,"_",inputFile,sep=""), row.names=FALSE)}
}

if (headerSpec == 'no_header') {
    inputData<-read.table(inputFile,header=FALSE)
    for (i in 1:numberOfResamples) {write.table(inputData[sample(nrow(inputData),replace=TRUE),], paste("./bootstrap_",i,"_",inputFile,sep=""),
 sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)}
}
```

My problem is, the check for the existence of a file works, but for the header or integer don't.

Also, how can I, in the beginning, check if all three arguments have been passed?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason that this must be an R script and not a function?  All these checks would be more straightforward when using a function with arguments, and more portable.

Comment: `commandArgs` has a `trailingOnly` argument that would simplify your code.
You may want to check the number of arguments provided before checking their value.
In particular, `exists` returns `TRUE` if the variable exists:
in your case, it is either a string or `NA` (you can use `is.na` to check it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Vincent said, you should use the `trailingOnly` argument to `commandArgs` to simplify things.
As Konrad said, never, ever, ever compare directly to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
Also, use `assertive` for doing assertions.

```
library(assertive)
library(methods)    
cmd_args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

if(length(cmd_args) < 3)
{
  stop("Not enough arguments. Please supply 3 arguments.")
}
inputFile <- cmd_args[1]
if (!file_test("-f", inputFile)) 
{
  stop("inputFile not defined, or not correctly named."
}
headerSpec <- match.arg(cmd_args[2], c("header", "no_header"))
numberOfResamples <- as.numeric(cmd_args[3])
assert_all_numbers_are_whole_numbers(numberOfResamples)
assert_all_are_positive(numberOfResamples)

message("Success!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve all the checks, here's how:

```
if ((length(pcArgs) == 8) == FALSE) {stop("Not enough arguments. Please supply 3 arguments. Proper use example: Rscript bootstrapWithReplacementFile.R survival.csv header 50.")}
if (!file_test("-f",inputFile)) {stop("inputFile not defined, or not correctly named. Proper use example: Rscript bootstrapWithReplacementFile.R survival.csv header 50.")}
if ((headerSpec != 'header') == TRUE & (headerSpec != 'no_header') == TRUE) {stop("headerSpec not properly defined. Correct values: 'header' OR 'no_header'.")}
if (check.integer(numberOfResamples) != TRUE | (numberOfResamples>0) != TRUE) {stop("numberOfResamples not properly defined. Must be an integer larger than 0.")}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Don’t compare values explicitly to `TRUE` and `FALSE`, that’s an anti-pattern! For instance, just write `if (length(pcArgs) != 8)` etc.