# R script to read file got as an argument from command line

Tags: r, cmd, arguments

I cannot figure out how to read from file based on command line argument:( All the answers I was able too google seemed too complicated.

I want to run this script from command line and let $1 be replaced by name of file I pass as an argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
duplication<- read.table($1, header=T) 
options(scipen=10)
plot(duplication$x,duplication$y,col="blue");
```

So that by typing

```
R CMD BATCH script.R path_to_file
```

I want to read file and ideally output graph with the same name as was the name of file.

Comment: As it turns out a very similar question was asked [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345924/how-to-check-if-arguments-have-been-correctly-passed-to-rscript-on-windows) which may not only answer your question but give you some ideas.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808169/r-command-line-passing-a-filename-to-script-in-arguments-windows   Note that the accepted answer works on other platforms too.

Comment: You are right, I was trying R CMD BATCH and it turned out that Rscript worked on my mac. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I cannot accept your answer since it is comment. Should I delete my post then?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [commandArgs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/commandArgs.html). You should be able to do something like:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = FALSE)
```

Then access the arguments as a vector. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154190/1188479)